# Git: Keep changes in local repo & remove from index after adding to .gitignore

Tags: git, github, version-control

I modified few files in my local git repo Ex: `local.xml`. Added `local.xml` to local .gitignore file .

I want to keep `local.xml` modified in my local repo but remove from result when I do `git status` (I thinks it's called index?). 
It shows

> Changes not staged for commit:
>   modified:   local.xml

and

> Untracked files:     17-08-2015/

How I can clear screen which comes on `git status` so I don't get any conflict when I do git pull?

If I use below command, it removes my changes from local repo as well

```
git stash save --keep-index
git stash drop
```

Also if I do `git reset`, it will reset my file to older versions.

Comment: This question is a bit confusing.  If you want to hang on to work you have done but still be able to `git pull`, then `git stash` isn't a bad way to go.  Can you elaborate more on what the situation is?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I've updated the question. Please check if it makes sense. I believe stashing will save my changes somewhere and those changes will not be applied in my local repo at the same time? I want them to be applied in my local repo at the same time and I'm never going to push them from local to live. SO I don't want to track them.(I have added them to .gitignore but after modification due to which they appear in git status)

Comment: Is `local.xml` a tracked file (meaning, is it in the remote repository)?  Or, is simply a local config file which will never be versioned?

Comment: `local.xml` is in remote repo too. Though I don't want to track it any more(So added to .gitignore). But the content of local and remote `local.xml`  file is different which contains server specific configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you added `local.xml` to the `.gitignore` file, Git will still track it and it will still appear in your change set when you type `git status`.  One way to get around this is to tell Git to *temporarily* ignore it from the index.  You can do this via this command:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged local.xml
```

If you ever want your local changes to show up again in the index, you can undo this by typing:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged local.xml
```